# Adding a score at the end of my quiz in C#

Tags: c#, class, methods

I am trying to add a way to score a users answers to my quiz and display it at the end of the quiz. Trying to figure out an easy way of doing this where I won't have to completely redo my current code because I am an amateur coder at best. Any suggestions regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated. Here is a sample of my current code so you can see what I am working with. I have only included the first three questions, but there are 10 questions total:

```
using System;

namespace Quiz
{
class MultipleChoiceQuiz
{
    public static void CurrentQuestion(string correctAnswer)
    {
        do
        {
            string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userAnswer != "A" && userAnswer != "B" && userAnswer != "C" && userAnswer != "D")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError - Not a Valid Input - Please Enter Valid Input");
            }
            else
            {
                if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThat is correct!");
                    break;
                }
                else if (userAnswer != correctAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, that is incorrect.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
    public static void Questions()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name: ");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to the HC-130J Power-On Quiz " + firstName + ".\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Using the keyboard, please submit answers by using the \'ENTER\' key.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please submit answers in CAPITAL letter form only.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Ready to begin " + firstName + "? Hit the \'ENTER\' key now...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Question 1
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Question 1 - What position does the ramp contol knob need to be in? " +
                          "\n\nA. 3N \nB. 1 \nC. 6N \nD. A or C \n\nWhat is your answer " + firstName + "?");
        CurrentQuestion("D");
        Console.Write("\nPress \'ENTER\' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Question 2
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Question 2 - After power is applied to the aircraft, the battery needs to be turned off? " +
                          "\n\nA. True \nB. False \n\nWhat is your answer " + firstName + "?");
        CurrentQuestion("A");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\nPress \'ENTER\' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Question 3
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Question 3 - Above what temperature does air condition need to be applied to the aircraft while power is applied? " +
                          "\n\nA. 75 degrees Fahrenheit \nB. 100 degrees Fahrenheit \nC. 95 degrees Fahrenheit \nD. 85 degrees Fahrenheit \n\nWhat is your answer " 
                          + firstName + "?");
        CurrentQuestion("C");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\nPress \'ENTER\' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a static int within the class and add to it if the answer was correct from *CurrentQuestion* before you break.

**EDIT:** Here's an example:

```
using System;

namespace Quiz
{
class MultipleChoiceQuiz
{
    static int correct = 0; // this will hold the correct answers
    static int questions = 0; // this will hold the amount of questions

    public static void CurrentQuestion(string correctAnswer)
    {
        questions++;//this will add 1 when CurrentQuestion is called
        do
        {
            string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userAnswer != "A" && userAnswer != "B" && userAnswer != "C" && userAnswer != "D")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError - Not a Valid Input - Please Enter Valid Input");
            }
            else
            {
                if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThat is correct!");
                    correct++;//this will add 1 to correct when you answer correctly
                    break;
                }
                else if (userAnswer != correctAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, that is incorrect.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
    public static void Questions()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name: ");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to the HC-130J Power-On Quiz " + firstName + ".\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Using the keyboard, please submit answers by using the \'ENTER\' key.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please submit answers in CAPITAL letter form only.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Ready to begin " + firstName + "? Hit the \'ENTER\' key now...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Question 1
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Question 1 - What position does the ramp contol knob need to be in? " +
                        "\n\nA. 3N \nB. 1 \nC. 6N \nD. A or C \n\nWhat is your answer " + firstName + "?");
        CurrentQuestion("D");
        Console.Write("\nPress \'ENTER\' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Question 2
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Question 2 - After power is applied to the aircraft, the battery needs to be turned off? " +
                        "\n\nA. True \nB. False \n\nWhat is your answer " + firstName + "?");
        CurrentQuestion("A");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\nPress \'ENTER\' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Question 3
        Console.WriteLine("Chad Mitchell - ENGR 115 - USAF HC130J Power On Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Question 3 - Above what temperature does air condition need to be applied to the aircraft while power is applied? " +
                        "\n\nA. 75 degrees Fahrenheit \nB. 100 degrees Fahrenheit \nC. 95 degrees Fahrenheit \nD. 85 degrees Fahrenheit \n\nWhat is your answer " 
                        + firstName + "?");
        CurrentQuestion("C");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\nPress \'ENTER\' to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        //Score
        Console.WriteLine("You got " + correct + " out of " + questions + " correctly!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So I need to add a `int` variable to the `CurrentQuestion` method and then place it in-between the `Console.Writeline("\nThat is correct!");` and the `break;`? What do I set the `int` variable to when I add it to the method and what do you mean by "static"?

Comment: So I need to add a int variable to the CurrentQuestion method and then place it in-between the Console.Writeline("\nThat is correct!"); and the break;? What do I set the int variable to when I add it to the method and what do you mean by "static"? @SHsuperCM

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
public static void CurrentQuestion(string correctAnswer)
```

with

```
public static int CurrentQuestion(string correctAnswer)
```

If the answer is correct, return 1 else return 0.

Add a `score` variable in your `Questions` method:

```
public static void Questions()
{
    int score = 0;
```

Change your `CurrentQuestion(Answer)` calls to:

```
score += CurrentQuestion(...
```

Display `score` at the end.

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested but I am getting an error now on the `public static int CurrentQuestion(string correctAnswer)` that reads: _'MultipleChoiceQuiz.CurrentQuestion(string)': not all code paths return a value_. Everything else seems to be working appropriately except for that part.

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested but I am getting an error now on the public static int CurrentQuestion(string correctAnswer) that reads: 'MultipleChoiceQuiz.CurrentQuestion(string)': not all code paths return a value. Everything else seems to be working appropriately except for that part. @Chibueze Opata

Comment: You need to place `return 0;` at the end of the while loop for all incorrect answers.